# SQL Server Multitable Select with IF-Else

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following sql which returns Projects and related Contractors as well as document size info from three different tables. The sequence is: First Contractors are entered in the system, then Projects are entered for each Contractors, during with document sizes (sheets) are entered. So far so good: The following sql returns all projects along with appropriate Contractors and Sheets fine:

```
SELECT 
   dbo.generalcontractors.name,
   dbo.Projects.*,
   dbo.sheets.sheetsize,
   dbo.sheets.sheetid
FROM 
   dbo.generalcontractors 
INNER JOIN dbo.Projects ON (dbo.generalcontractors.uid = dbo.Projects.generalcontractorid)
INNER JOIN dbo.sheets ON (dbo.Projects.sheetid = dbo.sheets.sheetid) 
ORDER BY 
    dbo.Projects.projectdate DESC
```

Now, what needs to happen is that documents for individual projects are entered in a `ProjectDocuments` table. I have the following code which checks to see documents exist in the `ProjectsDocuments` table and return appropriate values; currently, the project id is hard-coded and it work.

Question is: how can I combine the following sql into the sql above? I am looking for one query result which will show any matching rows from the `ProjectsDocument` table and if no matching then will show 'Not Found'.

This is for SQL Server 2005.

Thanks!

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.projectsdocuments, dbo.Projects 
    WHERE projectsdocuments.projectid = Projects.projectid 
    AND Projects.projectid = 5) > 0 
    SELECT * 
    FROM projectsdocuments 
ELSE 
    SELECT 'Not Found' AS HighPrice
```

Comment: @marc_s. Thanks. Too early for me to give this up. Any other way I can return all this in one query?

Comment: Can you please post "CREATE" statements for the tables in question? That way I can use SSMS to debug.

Comment: Per this: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/ the RIGHT OUTER JOIN should work too. My current sql has this added:  ' Right OUTER JOIN dbo.projectsdocuments ON (Select * from Projects) ' but getting an error: ' An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'ORDER'. ' (see the ORDER in the original sql above). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to just simply add the `ProjectDocuments` table to your query, using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

If there are no matching rows in the `ProjectDocuments` table - then all columns from that table will be `NULL` - so capturing one of the columns and using the `ISNULL(<colname>, 'Not Found')` construction, you'd be displaying 'Not Found' when no values have been found in `ProjectDocuments`:

```
SELECT 
   gc.name,
   pr.ProjectDate, pr.Column1, pr.Column2, ....., pr.ColumnN,
   s.sheetsize,
   s.sheetid,
   ISNULL(pd.Name, 'Not Found') AS 'ProjectDocumentName',
   pd.Column1, ..., pd.ColumnN
FROM 
   dbo.GeneralContractors gc 
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Projects pr ON gc.uid = pr.GeneralContractorID
INNER JOIN 
   dbo.Sheets s ON pr.SheetID = s.SheetID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.ProjectsDocuments pd ON pr.ProjectID = pd.ProjectID
ORDER BY 
    pr.ProjectDate DESC
```

Two things I'd recommend doing:

- use meaningful **table aliases** (like `gc` for `GeneralContractor`, `pr` for `Project` and so forth) - it makes reading the queries just soooo much easier....
- **explicitly specify** the columns you want to to retrieve from the tables - that prevents unwanted surprises when suddenly your table has five BLOB columns more that get returned - even though you don't need them!

Comment: Okay, will try your solution now. Thanks!

Comment: The solution which works (except a minor error: p.ProjectID should be pr.projectID --no biggy though). Thank you guys so much!

Comment: The only problem with this statement is that it returns multiple records for the same Project. For example, if there are multiple documents per Project--as expected--then I see a bunch of rows with the same Project but with different document. I think I need some kind of 'Group By' here?

Comment: @Meengla: well, if you have multiple documents - yes, you'll get multiple rows - that's how relational JOINs work. What do you want to happen in this case?? If you have 5 documents - do you want to see (a) the first one, (b) a random one - or what??

Comment: Marc_s: Ideally, the documents should show as a list or array. But if that's too much to ask for then just something like 'Document Present' or 'Documents Absent' will work too. Thanks!

Comment: @Meengla: you cannot really have a *nested* list/array inside a single column value in SQL Server. You could e.g. show "4 documents present" or something, or you could concatenate together one of the attributes of the `ProjectsDocuments` table into a single string...

Comment: I think, as I said, simple strings like 'Present' or 'Absent' will do; this will enable the page's viewers (Asp.net page) to see if action is needed on some Projects or not. So how do I modify the query string to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: marc_s: Never mind. Figured out! Thanks for your help again! here it is ----                 SELECT gc.name, pr.*, pd.docfile, s.sheetsize
   FROM 
  projects pr
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT projectid,   COUNT(*) docfile FROM projectsdocuments GROUP BY projectid ) pd ON (pd.projectid = pr.projectid)
 INNER JOIN dbo.Sheets s ON pr.SheetID = s.SheetID
 INNER JOIN dbo.generalcontractors gc  ON gc.uid = pr.GeneralContractorID
 ORDER BY  pr.ProjectDate DESC

Comment: I came to the solution partly by using subqueries, as in: http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

You should LEFT JOIN ProjectDocuments, and SELECT the appropriate fields. Use ISNULL to replace one of those fields with 'Not Found' if there are no corresponding documents.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you could add that LEFT JOIN in my first sql above?! Thanks.

Comment: According to: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/ LEFT OUTER JOIN should work and automatically return Nulls if not matched?. But when I do LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.projectsdocuments ON (dbo.projectsdocument.projectid = dbo.Projects.projectid) then I get error: 'The multi-part identifier "dbo.projectsdocument.projectid" could not be bound.'

Comment: Ooops! Had the table name wrong. The new LEFT OUTER JOIN is: ' LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Projects ON (dbo.projectsdocument.projectid = dbo.Projects.projectid) '
        I think I am getting closer!